# Converting my custom url as Friendly in dotnet nuke

Tags: dotnetnuke, friendly-url

I create a managenews.aspx. every news have a 16 digit id. while redirecting to the editnews page i am redirecting it like this. www.mysite.com?newsid=123456789-1011121345&userid=2

id i am passing a query string and read it the page.

is there any way i can change my url like www.mysite.com/newsid/123456789-1011121345/Userid/2 in dotnet nuke

Answer (score 2):

You should use the NavigateURL method, or the EditURL method in DNN.

DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL(TabId, string.emtpy, "newsid=####&userid=2"

TabId assumes you are inheriting from PortalModuleBase in you ascx.

though in DNN your URL also would include the page name, unless you use some other URL rewriting.

Comment: I tried this. but tab id is coming in the url. and all my html images are disappering. please suggest some good method in dnn for url rewrite for the above problem.

Comment: Your images would be disappearing because you aren't referencing them with the proper path, change your references to the images. As for TabId, that's the way the URLs work unless you use something like URLMaster from Ifinity.com.au